# Using jQuery to get json data returns invalid label error

Tags: json, jquery

I have this code, and have also tried something similar using the $.getJson function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var kiva_url = "http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json";

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: kiva_url,
            data:"format=json", 
        success: function(data){
            alert("here");
            jQuery.each(data.loans, function(i, loan){
                jQuery("#inner_div").append(loan.name + "<br />");
            });
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });

});
```

When I look in Firebug it is returning an "invalid label" error.  I've searched around a bit some people refer to using a parser to parse the results.  I can see the results coming back in Firebug.  Can someone point to an example of what I should be doing?

The Firebug error:

> invalid label
>   http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json?callback=jsonp1249440194660&_=1249440194924&format=json&
>   Line 1

Sample output of what the json looks like can be found here:
http://build.kiva.org/docs/data/loans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found the answer...it looks like kiva does not support jsonp which is what jquery is doing here -

http://groups.google.com/group/build-kiva/browse_thread/thread/9e9f9d5df821ff8c

> ...we don't have plans to support JSONP. 
>   Supporting this advocates poor
>   security practices and there are
>   already some good ways to access the
>   data from JavaScript that protect your
>   application and your users.  Here's a
>   great article on the subject:
>
> http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/10/json-and-browser-security/
>
> While the risk to Kiva lenders is low
>   now since we are only dealing with
>   public data, allowing private lender
>   data to be imported via script tags is
>   a risk further down the road.  Our
>   thought is the risk (and complexity
>   added to create secure applications)
>   is not worth the benefit to
>   developers.
>
> Writing a server-side proxy for the
>   feeds you need is the most common
>   solution to accessing data in
>   browser-based applications.  Some
>   other tricks exist using iFrames.  The
>   best hope is the new breed of client-
>   based technologies/standards that will
>   let browser-based JavaScript access
>   cross-domain resources securely (
>   http://dev.w3.org/2006/waf/access-control/
>   http://json.org/JSONRequest.html ). 
>   Some tools like BrowserPlus and Gears
>   let you play with these today, but you
>   won't be able to depend on these in
>   the wild for a while.
>
> As a final note, I'll point out that
>   anyone using JSON responses in
>   JavaScript should either parse JSON
>   explicitly or validate the JSON before
>   taking eval() to it.  See here:
>
> http://www.JSON.org/js.html
>
> Linked from the page is a great
>   reference implementation of the
>   proposed ECMAScript JSON parser
>   interface, JSON.parse().
>
> Cheers, skylar

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can help with jsonp:

http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Answer (score 2):

When you return the data, are you returning it with the correct content type and as a method?

You should return your data as follows (php 5 example):

```
$return = "my_callback_method(" . json_encode( array('data'=>'your data etc') ). ")";

while (@ob_end_clean());
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-type: application/json');
print_r($return);
```

In your calling javascript code, you must have a method to match the callback method you returned, in this case:

```
function my_callback_method( returned_data ){
}
```

So, your complete calling js should look something like the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var kiva_url = "http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json";

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: kiva_url,
        data:"format=json", 
    dataType: "jsonp",
    error: function(xmlhttp,error_msg){
            alert("error"+error_msg);
    }
});

function my_callback_method( data ){
   alert("here");
   if( data && typeof(data) == 'object') ){
     jQuery.each(data.loans, function(i, loan){
         jQuery("#inner_div").append(loan.name + "<br />");
     });
   }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the error occur? Does error occur when you try to loop through the ajax data and append it to the inner_div? If yes, please show us what the data.loans look like.

Also, there is a typo in your code:

```
            jQuery.each(data.loans, function(i, loan){
                    jQuery("#inner_div").append(loan.name + "<br />"); //It should be loan.name and not laon.name
            });
    },
```

Comment: Fixed my typo - I believe it's on the retrieve- If I take out that jquery loop I still get the error.

Comment: which line gives the error? Can you include Firebug error snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-getjson-invalid-label

Simply wrap your Json response with your callback request
E.g. `jQuery16203473509402899789_1315368234762({"Code":200,"Message":"Place added successfully","Content":""});`
where 
    `jQuery16203473509402899789_1315368234762` is your callback request (you can get it via querystring)
    `{"Code":200,"Message":"Place added successfully"}` is your JSON response