# JQuery ajax() method

Tags: jquery

My ajax method always returns ServiceFailed although WCF service method returns successfully (I verified by setting breakpoints). The code is shown below. What could be the wrong?

```
function LoginToServer(name, password) {
    server = "localhost:1706";
    Type = "GET";
    var encodeusername = $.base64.encode(encode_utf8(name.value));
    var encodepwd = encode_utf8(password.value);
    var params = 'username=' + encodeusername + '&password=' + encodepwd + '&clientip=none';
    Url = "http://" + server + "/WCF/Test/TestService.svc/rest/Login?" + params;
    ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    DataType = "jsonp";
    ProcessData = true;
    JsonpCallback = "alertResponse",
    method = "Login";
    CallService();
}


function CallService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service
        data: Data, //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
        jsonpCallback: JsonpCallback,
        success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
```

WCF Service method is defined as below:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/Login?username={username}&password={password}&clientip={clientip}")]
    AuthenticationStatus SlideViewerLogin(string username, string password, string clientip);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you check to verify that your data type returned from your webservice matches the expected datatype (jsonp)

Comment: How can I check this? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi...check out the blog post which is in my answer will resolve your issue...

Comment: Could you paste your serverside code?

Comment: @bygrace: Please see the modified post above.

Comment: Have you opened up firebug and seen what the response is? If so could you paste that too?

Comment: @bygrace - I don't see any response object in the watch window? Which one you are interested?

Comment: If you are in the console in FF you can see the request go across and if you open it you will see the request and response. What is the response?

Comment: @bygrace - here is the response :invalid label
{"IsAdmin":false,"IsPrivilegesModified":false,"Privileges":null,"SessionID":"edd...

Comment: Sorry, it looks cut off. Can you put it in the post?

Comment: invalid label {"IsAdmin":false,"IsPrivilegesModified":false,"Privileges":null,"SessionID":"eddca3f8-281d-4fea-b92b-3ce021ab9bf9","UserStatus":8,"WarningCount":0}

Comment: @bygrace - see the error response above from Console tab.

Comment: On the JS side change your DataType to "json" rather than "jsonp". Check this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240889/json-response-from-jquery-get-raises-invalid-label

Comment: @changing from "jsonp" to "json" doesn't work.I get 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: hi check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java from jsonp ...download code and check it must work for you

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For cross domain call check this**

[**Calling Cross Domain WCF service using Jquery/JavaScript**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java)

**For WCF call**

there might be some issue with WCF service also have look to this blog post which help you to figure out the error you are facing :

#### Create REST service with WCF and Consume using jQuery

try to pass the data something as below in json format

```
var msg2 = { "UserName": "Denny", "Password": "abc123" };
 Data = JSON.stringify(msg2);
```

Comment: When I try with this approach, I always get below error. 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)'

Comment: @codematrix - download code from here and try  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the variable "params" where you have  data: Data,.  It's looking for something in data, but I don't see a variable named data in your functions.