# Invalid label error on jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I am using following code to read json response from the spring 3.0 rest webservice.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/images/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType:'application/json',
            success: function(data) { alert(""); },
            error: function() { alert('Error occured.. !'); },
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });
    });

    function setHeader(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
```

If i use $.getJSON i am getting valid JSON in response.

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
    alert("Within readky function..");
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/images/',
    function(json) 
    {
        alert(json); 
    });
  });
```

If i invoke webservice from browser i am getting following response which is a valid JSON.

```
{"imageList":[{"itemName":"tv","picName":"image1.jpg","price":20,"id":0},{"itemName":"radio","picName":"image2.jpg","price":5,"id":0}]}
```

One more thing i would like to mention. $.getJSON works fine on chrome and firefox but fails on IE.

Please suggest.

Comment: Sure, that's valid json, but you're requesting *jsonp* in your first example. jsonp would have a wrapper, so your response is *not* valid jsonp. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3240965/551093

Comment: for jsonp response needs to be wrapped at server

Comment: If i run following snipped from the same container with datatype as JSON i am getting a valid response. 

NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/images/

If i run it as file in browser then i am getting 403 error message. I am using