# .ajax returning json object, but no success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using JQuery's .ajax method to call to a URL which returns a JSON encoded string. I can see the object returned from the GET in the debugger, but for some reason I'm not falling into the success function. Any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
        type:     "GET",
        url:      'http://search.issuu.com/api/2_0/document?q=jamie',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            alert('Success!');
        }
});
```

[image: Debugger]

Comment: Do it like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xrk4z6ur/**, and open the console (F12) and tell us what you're getting ?

Comment: It's returning an object, so you don't need to use JSONP.

Comment: It's obviously not returning an object, how would an external page ever be able to return an object. On the other hand, it's not returning JSONP either, just regular JSON, so the same origin policy comes into play, and this can't be done.

Comment: This is probably related to making a JSONP request cross origin when the response is not wrapped in a function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240889/json-response-from-jquery-get-raises-invalid-label

Comment: jsfiddle says that there's a syntax error in the json string:

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement document:1
Arguments { 0: Object, 1: "parsererror", 2: Error, 2 more… } _display:30

Comment: When I change the datatype to json then I am getting the cross origin error. It appears that the folks at issu.com need to change their api perhaps.

Comment: @Malchesador Or, you need to use it as it was intended. Doesn't appear to be intended for use with a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://developers.issuu.com/api/search/searchrequest.html), it shows that the proper way to make a jsonp request requires a `jsonCallback` parameter.

**Code:**

```
$.ajax({
        type:     "GET",
        url:      'http://search.issuu.com/api/2_0/document?q=jamie&jsonCallback=?',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            alert('Success!');
        }
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xrk4z6ur/2/

jQuery will by default use `callback=?` for a jsonp request. In this case, the API accepts `jsonCallback`. Adding `jsonCallback=?` to the url will let jQuery handle it properly.

Comment: Yes this works. The problem however is that issu.com is sending a malformed json string so I can't parse it with jQuery.parseJSON(). Hopefully they'll fix that.

Comment: 1) I'm not getting malformed json. 2) JSONP is already parsed - it's giving you back a function (if you specify jsonCallback=callback, for example) with the json object as its parameter.

Comment: @Malchesador Do you have proof of that? From the example you gave, issu.com is doing everything correctly. See http://jsfiddle.net/xrk4z6ur/4/, where I output the response object to console and show an example of how to use the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jsonp you should specify a callback GET parameter like &callback? 
On server side return the callback with your desired data as argument (json encoded)

Comment: I don't have any control over what they're doing at issu.com.

Comment: Then you can't do a jsonp callback, and more importantly you can't do a cross-site request like you want. The server needs to be jsonp aware and willing in order to do what you want.