# Weather forecast from WOEID (using YQL or rss) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql, weather, yahoo-api

Is there any way of getting the weather forecast from woeid in javascript?

I tried using rss feed of yahoo, but couldn't get it to work. here is my code

```
    var url = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=" + encodeURIComponent('WOEID here');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: function(data) { console.log(data); },
        success: function(data) { alert("success"); }
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest way to get the info you want using jQuery and YQL:

```
var woeid = "26355493";

var $url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?";

$.getJSON($url, {
    q: "select * from xml where url=" +
       "\"http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=" + woeid + "\"",
    format: "json"
  }, function (data) {
    console.log(data.query.results.rss.channel);
  }
);​
```

[The query in the YQL console...](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20xml%20where%20url=%22http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=26355493%22)

[The JavaScript code in jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/gWbQa/1/)

Comment: This doesn't return the full weather information. How can you get humidity, atmospheric data, etc with it?

Comment: OK I updated the code to output all the data to the debug console for you. The YQL and jsfiddle links are also updated. While making these changes I found that `select * from rss` actually only returned a subset of the data compared to `select * from xml` so I changed that too.

Comment: Excellent! really helped me to resolve issue quickly. my vote +1

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the Weather API returns its results in `RSS` format, while your function is expecting them in `jsonp` format. Consider using [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) to fetch the weather `RSS` feed for you, process it, and return it in `jsonp` format.

Here's a pipe that does something similar:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=4d160cd8ed9d6d78164213928a51507d

Answer (score 0):

As dragon suggested, I created a Yahoo Pipe - here is my complete code; the url in the code is the Yahoo Pipe I created.

```
$(function(){
   var url = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=e33143abd20b19a0173b3a4b479fa4d3&_render=json&w=YOURWOEIDHERE";

   function createRequest() {
       try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
       return null;
   }
   var request = createRequest();
   request.open("GET", url, true);
   request.onreadystatechange = callback;
   request.send(null);

   function callback() {
       if(request.readyState != 4) { return }
       Obj = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
       console.log(Obj);
   }
});
```

references:
Yahoo Pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=e33143abd20b19a0173b3a4b479fa4d3
[jQuery 1.5 - JSON error invalid label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395118/jquery-1-5-json-error-invalid-label)