# Javascript invalid label error

Tags: javascript, jquery, label

I am sorry if this question is a repeat of someother. I have looked into some of them but they don't answer my particular question.

I get an "invalid label" error where I am printing my alert statement in the code below:

```
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
        if( $('map#map').length > 0 ){
            //alert('found a map!');
            $('map#map area').each($area,
                function(i, val){
                    alert('Found: ' + val ):
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```

I get the same error is I do the following: `alert('Found: ' + $(this) );`

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, please?

ps: the elements I am attempting to read are as follows:

```
<map id="map" name="imgmap20116293122">
<area alt="" coords="11,76,97,127" href="" shape="rect" target="" title="" />
<area alt="" coords="12,28,96,74" href="" shape="rect" target="" title="" />
<area alt="" coords="100,28,160,73" href="" shape="rect" target="" title="" />
<area alt="" coords="162,28,221,73" href="" shape="rect" target="" title="" />
<area alt="" coords="502,239,549,282" href="" shape="rect" target="" title="" />
<area alt="" coords="473,284,554,330" href="" shape="rect" target="" title="" /-->
```

Comment: shot the HTML too .. cant decide

Comment: Is the $area? Should it not be $(area) ?

Comment: possible duplicate. But, more relevant to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230897/using-jquery-to-get-json-data-returns-invalid-label-error

Comment: Matt's answer below solves your issue. Sometimes when Firebug doesn't give you a useful enough error, using the WebKit debugger helps isolate the syntax error. In this case, I pasted the code into a Firebug console and the error wasn't as descriptive as the WebKit console's error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a colon at the end of the statement. Change that to a semicolon.

Also, you have an extra parameter `$area` in the `each` method, which is not supported. If you remove that, the code will run.

Comment: Also there is no needs in the `.length` check before `.each` call, I think. Iterator callback will not be called, if jQuery object has no elements.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a `:` instead of a `;` at the end of the line. Change

```
alert('Found: ' + val ):
```

to

```
alert('Found: ' + val );
```

---

See also [label @ MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Answer (score 1):

You put a colon in stead of a semicolon:

```
alert('Found: ' + val );
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Too-long-staring-at-the-same-code syndrome. I apologize for wasting your time.